# OpenCV parallel computing descriptors?

Tags: multithreading, opencv, sift, surf

I am developing an object-recognition system. I found that the critical part of my algo is the

```
extractor.compute();
```

(After having `detector.detect()` keypoints)

Is there any way to let compute the feature vector with more core? I can use up to 8 core.

Comment: If you build with TBB opencv will use multicores where possible

Comment: Do you have intel TBB installed? Did you check the USE_TBB box?

Answer (score 1):

Opencv already implements multithread framework for this. Check that you compiled opencv with threading option 'ON'. You should go for an opencv documentation reading, `gpu::SURF_GPU` may interest you.

You can run cmake again to see the compilation options you used.

Comment: note gpu:: uses CUDA (ie an Nvidia graphcis card) it doesn't do multi threading on CPU cores

Comment: @martin Obviously. I thought it was acquired. Thx for exactness.

Comment: As Martin said, look for WITH_TBB option.